# Parse Json Data into HTML without having Json array name

Tags: html, json, swing, parsing, model-view-controller

I have a web service returning list of json data. But the data does not have array name.
JSON Format of Data is shown below:

```
[{"itemno":1256,"offerPercent":10,"bulkDiscount":20,"regQtyBuyLimit":10,"offerQtyBuyLimit":5,"minReOrderLevel":2,"pkg":"5kg","addedOn":"2015-10-11","updatedOn":"2015-10-12","mrp":500,"regPrice":400,"minBulkQty":50}]
```

This is coming from mysql via web service call.

I want to parse it into html table.

My question is: how to parse data without arrayname or how to define the name of the array then parse it?

Comment: What kind of array name are you referring to? Your pasted JSON data is illegal, note the last ",". If you remove that using `var jsonData = JSON.parse('[{"itemno":1256,"offerPercent":10,"bulkDiscount":20,"regQtyBuyLimit":10}]')` parses your JSON string to a type of `object`, which you can address as `jsonData[0]`.

Comment: @kayess i have edited the json data ; the "," was by mistake typed.

Comment: @kayess   array name means the name that is shown on the json data at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I have solved my problems by myself.
This time i will show u how.

Here is the complete code of jsp file:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Lets See</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/item',
                function (json) {
                    var tr;
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].itemno + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].offerPercent + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].bulkDiscount + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].regQtyBuyLimit + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].offerQtyBuyLimit + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].minReorderLevel + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].pkg + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].addedOn + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].updatedOn + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].mrp + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].regPrice + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].minBulkqty + "</td>");
                        $('table').append(tr);
                    }                   
                });
            });   
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ItemNo</th>
            <th>OfferPercent</th>
            <th>BulkDiscount</th>
            <th>regQtyBuyLimit</th>
            <th>offerQtyBuyLimit</th>
            <th>minReorderLevel</th>
            <th>pkg</th>
            <th>addedOn</th>
            <th>updatedOn</th>
            <th>mrp</th>
            <th>regPrice</th>
            <th>minBulkqty</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Get Item</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

get response from server (either if you use simple http form submit request or ajax call ) on success call $.parseJSON(responseData) on responseData.

Use alert to verify your data.

Comment: i don't know how to parse a json data without array name ...... please help me on this ...

Comment: you have data then just use this function